# geeglm in R: Error message about variable lengths differing

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to run a GEE model with a logit outcome, using the following code.

```
mod.gee <- geeglm(general_elec~activity_outside_home+econ_scale_6_pt, 
                              data=D_work_small, id="pidlink", 
                              family=binomial(link="logit"), corstr="ar1")
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = general_elec ~ activity_outside_home+ : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(id)')
```

My data is longitudinal data from two waves of a survey. I have tried omitting responses with NAs, and changing the data types of the variables, but nothing has worked. Any suggestions, or has anyone run into this problem before?

My data is structured as follows:

```
> head(D_work_small)
     pidlink econ_scale_6_pt activity_outside_home general_elec wave age female java educ_level   pid_unit
1  001220001               3                     1            1    3  48      0    0          1 0012200013
10 001220002               3                     1            1    3  47      1    0          1 0012200023
19 001220003               2                     1            1    3  27      0    0          4 0012200033
77 001250003               2                     1            1    3  27      0    0          1 0012500033
79 001290001               2                     1            1    3  52      0    0          1 0012900013
88 001290002               2                     1            1    3  49      1    0          1 0012900023

> summary(D_work_small)
   pidlink          econ_scale_6_pt activity_outside_home  general_elec         wave      
 Length:44106       Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.0000        Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:0.0000        1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:3.000  
 Mode  :character   Median :3.000   Median :1.0000        Median :1.0000   Median :4.000  
                    Mean   :2.894   Mean   :0.7048        Mean   :0.8304   Mean   :3.608  
                    3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000        3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
                    Max.   :6.000   Max.   :1.0000        Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :4.000  
      age             female            java          educ_level    pid_unit        
 Min.   : 14.00   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.0   Length:44106      
 1st Qu.: 26.00   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.0   Class :character  
 Median : 35.00   Median :1.0000   Median :0.0000   Median :2.0   Mode  :character  
 Mean   : 37.35   Mean   :0.5118   Mean   :0.4171   Mean   :2.2                     
 3rd Qu.: 47.00   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:3.0                     
 Max.   :999.00   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.0
```

Comment: Your `id` variable should be without quotes, as in `id=pidlink`. Also as it is converted to numeric in the calculation (via `as.numeric`), you should convert it from character to `factor` ie `id=factor(pidlink)`. [Aside, it also looks as if `activity_outside_home` and `econ_scale_6_pt` should be factor variables and you should order your data by `pidlink`].